# Any function that equals $0$ a.e. implies Lebesgue integral also equals $0$

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

I'm currently tackling the following:

> Show, from first principles that if $f(x)=0$ for a.e. $x$, then $\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x)dm(x)=0$

Now I know how to do this for the other way around (integral equals zero implies that the function equals zero) but am not sure if there is anything else I should do to make sure this way works.

Any help is much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: $f$ is clearly a simple function (or can be represented as one). Recall the definition of integration for simple functions...

Comment: Actually, the "other away around" is not true in general, but it is true with the additional hypothesis that $f$ is nonnegative, for example.

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist $f$ need not be a simple function. It may well assume infinitely many values on the null set where it is nonzero.

Comment: @Bungo hence my parenthetical :) though I suppose I should have said there “is equivalent to one”...

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist Right, there's no context so we don't know how much the OP knows. If we work straight from the definition, then any simple function approximating $f^+$ or $f^-$ from below can only be nonzero on a null set, hence such a simple function must have integral zero. Since $\int f^+$ and $\int f^-$ (and hence $\int f$) are defined by suprema over sets of such simple functions, the result follows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose first that $f\geq 0$ and consider a non-negative simple function $g:x\mapsto\sum_{k=1}^n a_k1_{A_k}(x)$ with $g\leq f$ and $\forall k, a_k\neq 0$. Since $f=0$ a.e, $g=0$ a.e, hence $P(\bigcup_{k=1}^n A_k)=0$, thus $\forall k, P(A_k)=0$, so $$\int g = \sum_{k=1}^n a_k P(A_k)=0$$

Since $f$ is the pointwise increasing limit of simple functions $g_n$ with $g_n\leq f$, the monotone convergence theorem yields $\int f = 0$.

Dropping the non-negativity assumption on $f$, write $f=f^+-f^-$. Since $f=0$ a.e, it follows that $f^+=0$ a.e and $f^-=0$ a.e. Hence $$\int f= \int f^+ - \int f^- = 0-0 =0$$

Comment: Nice, assuming the OP knows the MCT. (No context given, hence we must make assumptions :-) Minor nit: $P$ should be $m$ in this context.